# How to get the longest and shortest lines from a standard input in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I'm writing a script to get the longest and shortest lines from a standard input without success.

To invoke the program you should use something like:

```
LongShort.sh /tmp/filetest.txt
```

My script currently look like this.

```
#! /bin/bash LongShort.sh

longest=0
shortest=0


while read line
do
   linelength=${#line}
   if [ "$linelength" -gt "$longest" ]
   then
     $longest = $line
     $longestlength = $linelength
   elif [ "$linelength" -lt "$shortest" ]
     then
        $shortest = $line
        $shortestlength = $linelength
   fi
done < $2

echo $longestlength $longest
echo $shortestlength $shortest
```

Does anyone see what's wrong?

Comment: also take care of case where all lines are same size - keep max and min checks separate

Comment: longestlenght = $linelenght

Comment: `read` will read words rather than lines. You should be able to change that with `$IFS`.

Comment: @pawel7318 `read` reads by line but will split into words (based on `IFS`) if given multiple variables (splits even with one variable but assigns all words to last variable given).

Comment: @SandyElms has the right of it. Your assignment statements get confused part way through the script. The first three are correct the ones after that are not. You assign to bare names (not `$` prefixed) and the `=` cannot have spaces on either side of it.

Comment: See http://www.shellcheck.net/. It is great at catching clear errors as well as questionable constructs.

Comment: If you do not need to find the best solution, try this one: put char count to the beginning of the all lines with spaces by using `sed` and `wc`, sort it with `sort`, take first and last line from this result with `tail` and `head`. This takes only one line.

Comment: God, please bless one-liners.

Comment: @EtanReisner you are right ! It's always great to learn something new, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your script:

1. You're sometimes using `longest` to store the longest line, and sometimes using it to store the longest line *length*
2. When you assign a value to a variable in bash, the syntax is `<name>=<value>` with no spaces.  Using the `$` sign in the left hand side is (generally) wrong, because you're trying to assign something to the value stored in the variable.  So lines like `$longest = $line` should be changed to `longest=$line`
3. By initializing `shortest` to `0`, you assure yourself that the shortest line will never be found, because no line will ever have a length shorter than `0`.  You need to initialize it to a value that's at least as big as the shortest line in the file.

Edit: as you pointed out yourself, it's better to split the inside of the loop into two `if` statements to catch cases where the shortest line is first, or all the lines are the same length.

Here's my version:

```
#!/bin/bash LongShort.sh

# use *length variables to store the lengths
longestlength=0
shortestlength=5000  # initialize shortestlength to something big


while read line
do
   linelength=${#line}
   if [ $linelength -gt $longestlength ];
   then
     longest=$line  # assign values properly
     longestlength=$linelength
   fi
   if [ $linelength -lt $shortestlength ];
   then
        shortest=$line
        shortestlength=$linelength
   fi
done < $2

echo $longestlength $longest
echo $shortestlength $shortest
```

Comment: Your script seems to correct my errors just fine but now I see something that I didnt think before. If the first line is the shortest the elif wont catch it and so for it might be best to have a second if instead. What do you think?

Comment: Yep, also that will catch the case where all the lines are the same length.  I'll edit the answer to reflect the case.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf '%s\n' a bb ccc dddd eeeee | awk '
    NR==1{long=short=$0;next}
    length($0) > length(long){long=$0}
    length($0) < length(short){short=$0}
    END{print "long=" long "|short=" short}
'
```

Output :

```
long=eeeee|short=a
```